# A list of factors of a binary word

Tags: list-manipulation

I want a list of ALL contiguous sub-sequences of a binary word w, say w={r,d,r,r,d}.

I have;

w = {r, d, r, r, r}; {Drop[w, 1], Drop[w, -1]} which gives the length 4 subsequences : {{d, r, r, d}, {r, d, r, r}}.

How do I get All of such sub-sequences?

That is I want: Input:={r,d,r,r,d}

Output:{ {r,d,r,r,d}, {d,r,r,d},{r,d,r,r},{r,r,d},{d,r,r},,{r,d,r},{r,d},{r,r},{d,r},{d},{r},{}}

(not necessarily in this order).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861517/sequential-subsets-of-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Subsequences`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsequences.html):

```
list = {r, d, r, r, d};

DeleteDuplicates @ Subsequences @ list
```

> ```
> {{}, {r}, {d}, {r, d}, {d, r}, {r, r}, {r, d, r}, {d, r, r}, {r, r, d}, 
>  {r, d, r, r},  {d, r, r, d}, {r, d, r, r, d}}
> ```

You can also use [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) with the option `Overlaps -> All`:

```
Union @ SequenceCases[list, {___}, Overlaps -> All]
```

> ```
> {{}, {d}, {r}, {d, r}, {r, d}, {r, r}, {d, r, r}, {r, d, r}, {r, r, d},
>  {d, r, r, d}, {r, d, r, r}, {r, d, r, r, d}}
> ```